# android byte array is shortening the numbers?

Tags: android, byte, nfc, mifare

In my little NFC related project i'm trying to set a byte[] as authentication key for the Mifare Classic 1k chips i'm using. When is set it like this:

```
private byte[] key = {(byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff};
```

it ends up being `-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`... Why is Android translating it like this, and, how should it really be coded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Android or NFC, this is is how Java works. `byte`'s are signed, which means that one of the bits is used as the sign. `0xff=11111111`, which happens to mean -1 for Java. Your MIFARE card doesn't care about this though, so your program should work fine.

Comment: Thank you already. But how many bytes should there be in the array? According to my retailer, the key should be 00 00 00 00 00 00. So that would be `{(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00}`, right?

Comment: The key is 48-bits, so that means 6 bytes. BTW, you don't have to cast  `0x0` to `byte`, only values exceeding the maximum byte value.